# Email verification via OTP in Nodejs failed without showing any error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern

I tried to send OTP for email verification in my MERN stack project. I used the "two-step-auth" module to send OTP. It worked fine for 1 week. But suddenly OTP stopped being sent without showing any error.

OTP sending function:

```
async function sendOTP(emailId) {
  try {
    const res = await Auth(emailId);
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.mail);
    console.log(res.OTP);
    console.log(res.success);
    return String(res.OTP);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  }
```

}

when I call it outputs this :

```
{
  status: 404,
  mail: 'anikislampantha104@gmail.com',
  success: false,
  message: 'Unable to send mail'
}
```

If I print OTP by writing this

```
otp_sent.then((otp_s)=>{
      
      console.log(otp_s);
    })
```

otp_s shows undefined

But last one week it was working just fine

Comment: If you can add which service you are using for sending email (Hosting or 3rd party) behind "`Auth`", I will be able to help you better.
Also please check the logs of the service / hosting provider for any possible errors logged in them.

Comment: service means?please name some example @HamzaTasneem

Comment: The emails you are sending must be going through some server. 
Examples include: 
3rd party services: SendGrid, Mailchimp etc
Hosting examples: anydomain.xyz (the emails you send also have them as name@anydomain.xyz

Comment: appauthenticator.1@gmail.com 
@HamzaTasneem

Comment: I followed this tutorial on GFG
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/email-verification-using-otp-in-nodejs/

Comment: This is an old library with less help given here:
https://github.com/saran-surya/two-step-auth
On searching it seems like the person who create this is sending emails through his "Heroku Account".
Did you turn on "Less secure apps" like it says in github Readme?